# "Famous Badges" should have a time limit on them

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, view-badges

This will negatively affect me, as I have been awarded a "Famous Question" badge a few times, but mostly on questions that are older than 2 years old. For a page on a heavily-trafficked website to garner 10k views in a span of 2 or more years is hardly what I would consider "famous". I would think an element of time should be considered, like reached 10k views in a span of a month or even 6 months.

Yes, it will make the "Famous Question" badge harder to get, but it is a gold badge, after all, and a "Famous Question" will actually be "famous", rather than old enough to collect 10k views.

Comment: I have 2 year old questions with only 200 views

Comment: ha jeez, you meta guys are harsh. is it really that bad of a question?

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @juergend thanks. as you can see i don't spend a whole lot of time here :)

Answer (score 20):

Nah...

Typically, when a question slowly accumulates 10k views over a period of time, it's because it is a high-ranking search engine hit. (aka Google bait)

These types of questions are especially important because they attract outside viewers who are actually searching for a specific answer to a problem. So they have long-term value and thus *deserve* the badge.

---

**In short:** I don't think we should be restricting the badge to questions that get viral spikes of attention early in their life.

Comment: But how is it famous if after a period of 3 or 4 years, it managed to accumulate 10k views? It just seems like if you post a question of relative appropriateness, eventually you will get a gold badge, regardless of how good the question actually is.

Comment: That's more of an argument for the misuse of the term "Famous". It could be renamed to something more accurate to what it's awarding. But that would be less intuitive.

Comment: I would think that "Famous" should represent something that reached a high level of popularity in a short period of time and something like a silver "Enduring" or "Classic" badge would be for questions that garner 10k votes after the "Famous" period is over. Maybe have a different gold badge for a question that got more than 10k votes in the post-famous time frame... "Everlasting Question" or something

Comment: @Jason While it makes more sense to split the badges, IMO, that's probably over-complicating the badge system. Shameless plug: I'd be more in favor of more gold *answer* badges. Since it's often the case where the asker gets 3 (Great, Famous, Stellar), and the answerer gets only 1 (Great).

Answer (score 12):

We don't track view counts over time at this point...so it's a non-starter from a technical standpoint.  More than that, it complicates the badge with no visibility into the restrictions unless we also build a UI showing the view counts over time that you could see...it's a lot of effort for a payoff that isn't there.

From a naming standpoint: thousands or tens of thousands of individuals have seen it...sounds famous to me.

Comment: I suggested a simple solution, that would not be a lot of effort to implement: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230866/track-views-once-per-day

Comment: @rubo77 That requires many things to happen, without fail, daily, and with a *lot* of storage in play.  Really unless you know all the details "not a lot of effort" is a terrible assumption to make about any project you don't have deep first hand knowledge of.