# What are the requirements to get the "Weed Eater" hat?

Tags: support, bug, winter-bash-2015, winter-bash

The hat's description says

> answer a question qualifying for the Tumbleweed badge that gets accepted

During the winter bash, I [answered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43052/2217) a question that *is* a [tumbleweed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed?userid=6385), and it got accepted; yet I did not get the hat. However [this guy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles#winter-bash) answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249201) and did get the hat. (What was the difference?)

So what are the exact requirements to get the [Weed Eater](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/weed-eater) hat?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To be very explicit, the question has to qualify for the Tumbleweed badge *at the time the answer is posted*. There is one exception however, which is that the number of views is disregarded. Because we don't track historical view count data, it's not possible to say whether a question had 60 views or fewer at a specific time. So we just dropped the viewcount from consideration alltogether.

Here are the exact requirements for the hat:

- The answer was posted during Winter Bash and is not a self-answer.
- The answer is accepted, has a score of at least 1, and is not deleted.
- The question is fully active (not closed, not deleted, etc.).
- At the time when the answer was posted,

  - the question was at least 7 days old,
  - there were no (active) comments on the question,
  - there were no (active) answers to the question, and
  - the question had a score of 0.

If all of those are met, the owner of the answer gets the Weed Eater.

Comment: Could you please clarify "active comments" part? Do old (more than a week old) comments qualify as "active"?

Comment: @DVK Yes, as long as they're not deleted.

Comment: @balpha Can you tell my why I did not get the badge for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34273257/2442804)? The user even got the Tumbleweed badge for the question - or is that the exact problem? Or should I actually ask a question for this "problem"?

Comment: @luk2302 Yeah, bug. Fixing.

Comment: @luk2302 Fixed, you have the hat now. Sorry about that, and thanks for the ping.

Comment: Woah, nice, thanks :)))