# 3 Tumbleweeds, no Lifesaver

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I went on a hunting trip for the [Lifesaver](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/lifesaver) hat on [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

[image: answer a question qualifying for the Tumbleweed badge that gets accepted]

and three of my answers to tumbleweeds were accepted:

1. [Cómo interpretar los resultados del profiler en Netbeans 8.1](//es.stackoverflow.com/a/41108/127)

   - No activity since May 2016.
   - No comments and no edits until I posted the answer ([timeline](http:////es.stackoverflow.com/posts/11369/timeline)).
   - 60 views now, but it had less views when it was accepted.
   - Accepted 2017-01-04 21:00:28Z (22 hours ago).
2. [Nodejs Proxy saliendo con conexion desde otro equipo](//es.stackoverflow.com/a/41680/127)

   - There was an edit 6d 23h+ before my answer, but I posted **after** it earned the Tumbleweed badge.
   - Accepted 2017-01-04 13:14:29Z (yesterday).
3. [Iconos de Formato Condicional de Excel, sin Formato Condicional](//es.stackoverflow.com/a/41576/127)

   - There were some comments before my answer, but after the Tumbleweed badge.
   - This one probably did not meet the requirements due to the comments.
   - Accepted 2017-01-03 13:11:40Z (2 days ago)

All 3 questions earned the [Tumbleweed badge](//es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed). However, I did not get the Lifesaver.

Is there a requirement I am not considering or is it a bug?

Comment: I think your answer has to have an upvote. IIRC, and I'll try to find the source for this, the question has to _still_ qualify _when_ you post the answer. As in, just having earned the badge isn't enough for you to get the hat from it, the question has to _still_ have low enough views, no edits, and no comments when you answer.

Comment: Found the source I was thinking of. Nothing official, but [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288901/) speculates that the requirements are the same/similar to last years version of this hat. Those requirements are talked about in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271032/) which is linked from the first. If the first answer is correct about the requirements being the same, then only the first and second answers will qualify, but they have to have a positive score first. [Source for the score.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288272/)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the previous requirements @Kendra. I didn't see the positive score clarification (edited Dec 21). If I can confirm I'll mark as duplicate. On the meantime, I'm re-tagging to [discussion].

Comment: Kendra is correct, the answers have to have a positive score to be considered for the hat. The first two answers appear to get you close to getting the hat.  But as far as the third answer, the comment on the question would disqualify you for the hat.