# Track views once per day

Tags: feature-request, statistics, views, timeline

Please start tracking views for all questions once per day.

This could be done database-economical, if only when a question is viewed at, there is a check, if today already is an entry in the views statistic, and only if not, then the actual viewcount is stored in that statistic. This way there will be maximal one entry for each question each day and only **if** there was **at least one view** today.

Once this is tracked, there could be made a statistic of how the views per day varies over time, which is relevant, if you want to see, in what era the question got most of its views (in the beginning, recently or due to a certain event...)

Comment: I guess that SE have this functionallity but for internal purposes only